# UWP: Live queries and searches with realm

Tags: c#, uwp, realm

I'm using Realm as my main database and sync engine and my question is that how do I do live queries for search?

for example when I use

```
var _age= 7;
Instance.All<Dog>().Where(d => d.Age == _age).AsRealmCollection();
```

and bind my listview to it, I need my view to be updated when I change the `_age` variable. As another word, I want to have a "Dynamic" query to my database. I want my view to be updated when I want to look for "Dogs" in different ages. But when I run this query again and assign new collection to ViewModel, my view does not update.

What shall I do?

UPDATE:

Here you can get a sample code so you can reproduce this issue:
https://github.com/Mohsens22/RelamTest

Also I must tell you that `IRealmCollection<T>` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` by default so if you add any items to the collection with a "Write transaction" the view will be updated. More info can be found [HERE](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet)

Comment: For ListView, `ObservableCollection` could be used to update the source dynamically, I could not reproduce your issue with this segment code, Could you share a simple sample that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I added a sample code including some more details. Please take a look

Comment: Please try to use two way model  `<ListView x:Name="itemListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Dogz,Mode=TwoWay}">`.

Comment: I've tried that. No result.

Comment: Before add `Mode=TwoWay` the `Change` looks not work. And the button works in my side after added `Mode=TwoWay`.

Comment: And you could test your code with  `var value = Dogz.GetHashCode();`, when you click your button your `Dogz` was recreated.

Comment: Change button works by itself. Just put a beak point after the last line of that code, you can see that it updates the collection but not the view.

Comment: Can you PR a hotfix ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177262/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-mohsen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code sample and I found `Dogz` will be recreate with `Instance.All<Dog>().Where(z => z.Age == nxt).AsRealmCollection();`. So you need two way bind model.

```
<ListView x:Name="itemListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Dogz,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

And this is [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) about bind that you could refer.